# importing and exporting from csv files

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

[image]So I am trying to create a code which can search the data file:

1. By surname to retrieve and display the details for a contact
2. By date of birth to retrieve and display all contacts with a birthday in a particular month.

Here is the code I have created:

```
def search():
    option = input('Please select to search by \n1. Surname\n2. D.O.B\n')
    if option == '1':
        surname = input('Please enter surname: ')
        while not surname.isalpha():
            surname = str(input('Please enter a valid surname: '))
        Myfile = open('Address book.csv', 'rt')
        for line in Myfile:
            if ',' + str(surname) + ',' in line:
                print(line)
            else:
                 print('No contacts found')
    elif option == '2':
        Validmonth = False
        while Validmonth == False:
            month = input('Please enter the birth month')
            if month >='13' and month <='0':
                print('Please enter a valid month')
            else:
                Validmonth = True
            Myfile = open ('Address book.csv', 'rt')
            for line in Myfile:
                if str(month) in line:
                    print(line)
                else:
                    print('No contacts found')
    else:
        print('Error, select a valid option')
        search()

search()
```

I keep getting this result when I try the code:

```
Please select to search by 
1. Surname
2. D.O.B
1
Please enter surname: Vickers
No contacts found
No contacts found
No contacts found
No contacts found
No contacts found
No contacts found
No contacts found
No contacts found
```

I want to know why? someone please help?

Comment: I hope the credentials in the picture here are fake ... if not, perhaps you may better obfuscate them

Comment: Could you please not destroy your question? By removing the bulk you remove all context for people to assess if they have the same problem and if my answer would help them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test for the surname on *every row*, then print `No contacts found` for every row that doesn't match.

Break out of the loop when you find the name, and use the `else` suite for the `for` loop instead:

```
for line in Myfile:
    if ',' + str(surname) + ',' in line:
        print(line)
        break
else:
    print('No contacts found')
```

`else` on a `for` loop only is executed if you exhausted the iterable, so when you did *not* break out of the loop early.

Your surnames are the *first* value on the line, so you would be better off testing if the line *starts* with the surname:

```
if line.startswith(surname + ','):
```

Pro tip: when reading CSV files, use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('Address book.csv', newline='') as myfile:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == surname:
            print(row)
            break
    else:
         print('No contacts found')
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me with one more thing?

Comment: If it is within the scope of this question, sure. If it is a whole new question, post a new question (after searching for answers here on Stack Overflow).

Comment: No, it's the same question. With the code above, my code isn't functioning at all. I keep getting the same response 'No contacts found').

Comment: @ConfusedChild24: Are you 100% certain that the text `,Vickers,` appears on a line in the file? You did not post a sample of your CSV file, so I cannot verify that for you.

Comment: I have now added the data I am using in my question. I'm definitely sure that it is there.

Comment: @ConfusedChild24: A screenshot of a Excel spreadsheet is not the same thing. :-) You need to show the text content of the CSV file *itself*. What if it is using tabs instead of commas, for example?

Comment: @ConfusedChild24: Also note that `Vickers` is listed in the *first* column, which would mean there is *no* comma before it on the line. My `csv` module version deals with that situation much better.

Comment: oh, urm.. how do I open that? And also, i tried adding your code in.. it doesn't work. :/ When I try opening the excel file, it shows up like in the picture although I saved it as CSV

Comment: @ConfusedChild24: Open it in notepad, or in Python and print it: `with open('Address book.csv') as addressbook: print(repr(next(addressbook)))` to print the first line as a python string literal. Copy that first line and paste that here.

Comment: Surname,Name,Address,City,Postcode,Telephone n.o,D.O.B,Email address
,,,,,,,
Jackson,Samantha,2 Heather Row,Basingstoke,RG21 3SD,01256 135434,23/04/1973,sam.jackson@hotmail.com

Comment: Note how `Jackson` has no comma before it. Neither will `Vickers`.

Comment: Hmm, but I don't understand. OKay vickers won't have a comma before it but if i don't add a comma then I wont be able to search for other surnames?

Comment: @ConfusedChild24: why not? Each surname is on a new line

Comment: @ConfusedChild24: adjusted. Try it out, experiment with the `csv` module from the command line. Python is easy to play with. :-)